# Java large heap in container environment

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, containers, jetty

I'm trying to run a Jetty webserver on kubernetes, it needs an extremely huge amount of heap ~ 250 GB in our production environment, ~ 50 GB in our test environment.

I'm using `jetty:9.4-jdk11`, I'm trying to avoid setting `Xms` or `Xmx` flags explicitly because the value is different between different environments, for that I thought depending on `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage -XX:InitialRAMPercentage` would be much better, but no matter what I try I can't get the `MaxHeapSize` to get past 32178700288 ~ 30 GB.

The Node which has only the Java app on it with a few tiny sidcars, has 64 GB of memory.

Dockerfile

```
FROM jetty:9.4-jdk11

ENV APP_WAR root.war
ENV APP_EXPLODED_WAR root/
ENV APP_DESTINATION_PATH $JETTY_BASE/webapps/
ENV APP_DESTINATION_WAR $APP_DESTINATION_PATH$APP_WAR
ENV APP_DESTINATION_EXPLODED_WAR $APP_DESTINATION_PATH$APP_EXPLODED_WAR

ADD . $APP_DESTINATION_EXPLODED_WAR

ENV JAVA_OPTIONS -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90 -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=90 -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -Xlog:gc*,stringdedup*=debug:file=/tmp/gc.log:time
```

The container resources settings

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: "8"
    memory: 60G
  requests:
    cpu: "6"
    memory: 60G
```

Based on these values I should be getting 90% of 60 GB `MaxHeapSize` ~ 54 GB, not 30 GB.
Any idea what am I is missing  ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `JAVA_OPTIONS`  environment variable is actually being applied (that is, do you see the output of that `PrintFlagsFinal` in the logs)?

Comment: Yes I see it, and I can confirm that it is being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JVM argument called `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` which is enabled by default on Java 11, is the cause, from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html).

```
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
    
Disables the use of compressed pointers. By default, this option is enabled, and compressed pointers are used when Java heap sizes are less than 32 GB. When this option is enabled, object references are represented as 32-bit offsets instead of 64-bit pointers, which typically increases performance when running the application with Java heap sizes of less than 32 GB. This option works only for 64-bit JVMs.
    
It’s also possible to use compressed pointers when Java heap sizes are greater than 32 GB. See the -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes option.
```

Just changing `-XX:+` to `-XX:-` as shown above will disables it.

Using `-XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes` is not recommended either in my case, from the same [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html).

```
-XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes=alignment

Sets the memory alignment of Java objects (in bytes). By default, the value is set to 8 bytes. The specified value should be a power of 2, and must be within the range of 8 and 256 (inclusive). This option makes it possible to use compressed pointers with large Java heap sizes.

The heap size limit in bytes is calculated as:

4GB * ObjectAlignmentInBytes

Note:

As the alignment value increases, the unused space between objects also increases. As a result, you may not realize any benefits from using compressed pointers with large Java heap sizes.
```

But I guess it is worth testing.